# Chrome does not render images correctly

Tags: google-chrome, website, pictures

here comes a toughy: 
I have problems with chrome displaying images correctly for about a couple of months now at least.

I already checked the Content settings and possible inflictions with my installed plugins. This problem does also come up using incognito mode and deleting the cache does not help as well. 
So here we go:

On almost, every website may be one or two images get displayed correctly. But the other ones appear as only a small bar. If I right click the image and open it in another Tab it does work fine. 
I suspect some kind of rendering issue, due to the partial image that is being displayed "correctly" and the varying size of the bar. 
Here is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFI8.jpg (sorry can't seem to be able to put the image in the text)

I use chrome 74.0.3729.131 and have a Win 10 1709

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I tried resetting the profiles as *spikey_richie* suggested and it did not help

**EDIT2:**

Other browsers work fine. I also tried the UASpoofer Plugin: 
Changing to another UA sometimes may results in more loaded images but not always.

Comment: Have you tried a reset of Chrome back to default? chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings?origin=userclick

Comment: Looks more like it’s not loading the images completely. How is it in other browsers?